# Das Trial oder der Trial?

Tags: grammar-identification

*Trial* is a foreign word, which means it "should" be neutrum. But in *Duden, das Deutsche Wörterbuch*, I found *trial* as maskulin as well as neutrum. So, my question is, when do you use this word as maskulin and when as neutrum?

Comment: Depends on context. _Trial_ is used for rough outdoor rides on (motor) bike (=> das), or as _court trial_ (=> der).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Know and accept (1), but also for trials with 4WD cars or even trucks (http://www.europatrucktrial.org/), but cannot agree with meaning (2) - Never heard that used for a court trial. I do, however, have come across this word in a linguistic context, denoting a specific numerus in Sursurunga.

Comment: @tofro Ich muss Dir bezüglich (2) rechtgeben. Ich hatte das auch noch nie gelesen/gehört (war einfach das Erste was mir eingefallen ist). _Der Wettbewerb_, wie von [_@janka_ vorgeschlagen](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/44177/28897) trifft's wohl besser.

Comment: The assumption: "Trial is a foreign word, which means it "should" be Neutrum." is wrong. There is not even a grain of truth in it. Get rid of it soon.

Answer (score 3):

The online version of Duden helps here regarding the different meaning.

> **[Tri­al, das](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Trial_Test_Pruefung_Sportart)**
>
> BEDEUTUNGSÜBERSICHT
>   Geschicklichkeitsprüfung für Motorradfahrer
>
> HERKUNFT
>   englisch trial, eigentlich = Probe, Versuch

([motorcycle trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorcycle_trials), word has English origin)

*versus*

> **[Tri­al, der](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Trial_Numerus)**
>
> Gebrauch: Sprachwissenschaft
>
> BEDEUTUNGSÜBERSICHT
>   Numerus, der eine Dreizahl ausdrückt
>
> HERKUNFT
>   lateinisch-neulateinisch

([Grammatical number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#Trial) in linguistics, word has Latin origin)

---

Due to the different origin, the words differ also in **pronunciation** (see [wiktionary.org](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Trial)):

das Trial  - [ˈtʀaɪ̯əl] (as close as the speaking German gets to the English pronunciation;)

*vs*

der Trial - [ˈtʀiːaːl], [tʀiˈaːl]

Answer (score 1):

*Trial is a foreign word, which means it "should" be Neutrum.*

No, foreign nouns get assigned their gender by the same complicated process all other German nouns got them. It's mostly about the ending of the stem, or the class of object described, but often enough a foreign word that has a German counterpart gets simply assigned the same gender.

Sometimes, it's not decided yet.

**Der Trial** is often used as a replacement for **der Wettbewerb** or going back to the original English meaning, **der Versuch** , and so it gets assigned the same gender.

**Das Trial** to me is an abbreviation of **das Trialbike**, a special kind of bike or motorbike you use to ride and jump over rocks and boulder, and borrows the gender from **das Fahrrad** or **das Motorrad**.

But some people may simply follow your idea foreign words should be neutral unless other people decide the gender for them.

Comment: Es beginnt so stark und stürzt dann so ab! Wenn das Wort sein Geschlecht bekommt wie jedes andere Wort, dann gibt es auch Begriffe die den sächlichen Artikel bekommen und damit den gleichen Artikel haben, wie das englische Wort. Daraus darf man dann aber nicht schließen, dass eine eine Same-Gender-Regel zum Zuge kam - es ist einfach zufällig das gleiche Geschlecht wie im Englischen. Wie Marzipanherz richtig schreibt ist Probe (f.) auch eine gültige Übersetzung und Same-Gender wäre außerdem allenfalls "das Trial" (It was a hard trial).

Comment: Außerdem ist "sächlich" nicht unentschieden, sondern ein eigenes, sprachlich vollwertiges Geschlecht. Man kann nicht sagen dass "das Messer" im Wartestand, weil sich andere noch nicht entschieden haben, ob es ein Männchen oder ein Weibchen wird. Dazu kommt, dass die Regel ohnehin nicht auf Fremdsprachen generell passt, denn Worte aus dem Französischen sind auch Fremdworte, aber das Französische hat kein sächliches Geschlecht. (Dennoch: Das Portemonaie aber der Trottoir, die Hollondaise).

Comment: Es ist völlig Wumpe, welches imaginierte Geschlecht das Wort im Englischen hätte. Es spielt nur eine Rolle, welche Assoziation zu einem deutschen Wort verwendet wird. *Der Trial* stammt aus der Sportberichterstattung, und da kamen anfangs sogar Ungetüme wie *Der Trial-Wettbewerb* vor, die eine Assoziation mit *der Sport* nahelegen. *Die Probe* weckt hingegen die Assoziation, dass es sich eben gerade nicht um den eigentlichen Wettbewerb handelte, was sinnwidrig ist.

Comment: Und doch, viele Leute sind der Meinung, dass Fremdworte sächlich sein sollten, weil sie in der Ursprungssprache ja kein Geschlecht hätten. Das ist aber schon immer eine Mindermeinung gewesen, und so werden diese Leute de facto in den Fällen überstimmt, in denen sich das Geschlecht im Sprachgebrauch auf männlich oder weiblich einpendelt.

Comment: Was jetzt den Unterschied zwischen "Probe" und "Versuch" ausmacht müsstest Du noch darlegen. Die meisten von uns haben in der Schule auch Tests geschrieben die ganz schön ernst waren, oder zur Aufnahme am Konservatorium muss man einen Aufnahmetest bestehen - mit der Mehrdeutigkeit von "Test" sind hiesige Sprecher also hinreichend vertraut.

Comment: Fremdwörter, die schon Zeit hatten, in der Sprache heimisch zu werden und etwa ganz normal in einem Tatort vorkommen können, bekommen das Geschlecht zugewiesen, dass einem äquivalenten dt. Wort zugewiesen würde, etwa "das Jogging", "der Smoking", "die Big Band". Bei neuen Wörtern glauben Halbgebildete oft, dass Wörter angelsächsischen Ursprungs sächlich seien, wenn auf sie im englischen mit "it" referenziert wird. Beispielsweise hörte man lange Zeit Leute "das Laptop" sagen - inzwischen ist "der Laptop" ziemlich kanonisiert. Leute, die wirklich gebildet sind oder gänzlich ungebildet sind …

Comment: … machen es dagegen von Anfang an nicht falsch. Während den Scheingebildeten nicht auffällt, dass sie für Sushi und Kamikaze das Geschlecht aus dem Handgelenk schütteln ohne die geringsten Kenntnisse Japanisch mitzubringen. Im Englischen ist aber "sächlich" trotzdem ein Geschlecht wie im Deutschen: He, she und it - ich zähle 3 Geschlechter, was zählst Du?